# Given two integers $A$ and $B$, find if there exists a non-negative integer $X$ such that $(A+X) | (B+X)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

#### Question

The question appeared on CodeChef Starters 62. The actual question statement is

> Chef has two integers $A$ and $B$ $(A≤B)$.
>
> Chef can choose any non-negative integer $X$ and add them to both $A$
> and $B$. Find whether it is possible to make $A$ a divisor of $B$.

There does exist a proof. The approach however is not similar to mine.

#### My Approach

Throughout the proof, we will be working with only *integers*.

$$\frac{B+X}{A+X} = K$$ where $X\geq0$ and $K>0$.

$$B+X = K(A+X)$$
$$B = KA+(K-1)X$$

Taking$\pmod A$ on both the sides.

$$B \equiv (K-1)X \pmod A$$

#### Problem

I do not know where to go from here. Is there a neat property or some theorem to resolve the
last statement?

To make it terrible, take $A=9$ and $B=10$. If I choose $K=2$ and $X=1$, the last statement of my approach so far makes sense. However, clearly $(9+1)\nmid(10+1) = 10\nmid11$. So there is definitely something wrong.

#### What I want to know

1. Where am I going wrong?
2. Does a valid proof exist in my approach if someone proceeds in a correct manner?

#### Important Links

1. [Question](https://www.codechef.com/submit/MAKEMULTIPLE?tab=solution)
2. [Existing solution](https://www.codechef.com/submit/MAKEMULTIPLE?tab=solution)

Comment: I don't know what Code Chef is, but is the idea to write code to help figure out what the answer is?

Comment: @Kimball Yes. However, *we do have to solve the question mathematically first*. The final program for this problem is very easy to write. Check if B-A < A. If it is, then an X exists else it does not. It is something similar. This is visible in the *Existing solution* link.

Comment: The core part of the problem lies in actually solving it mathematically.

Comment: You can also write it as $(a + x)(k - 1) = b - a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong in your approach is that you are not using equivalences, but only implications. It is true that $$\dfrac{B+X}{A+X}=K \quad \Longrightarrow \quad B \equiv (K-1)X \mod A$$

but the reverse implication is not true. So you can have examples of values of $A$, $B$, $K$ and  $X$ for which $B \equiv (K-1)X \mod A$ but for which $\dfrac{B+X}{A+X} \neq K$, as you found out.

Here is a way to make your approach work : one has $$\dfrac{B+X}{A+X}=K \Longleftrightarrow B+X = K(A+X) \Longleftrightarrow X(1-K)=AK-B \Longleftrightarrow X = \dfrac{B-AK}{K-1}$$

(one can assume that $K \neq 1$, otherwise you have $A=B$ and any $X$ works).

If $B-2A \geq 0$, then you can take $K=2$, and you get that $X=B-2A$ works.

If $B-2A < 0$, then for every $K >0$, you have $B-AK < 0$, so $\dfrac{B-AK}{K-1}< 0$, so you don't have any solution.

Finally, there are solutions if and only if $A=B$ or $2A \leq B$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It guided me and made me a little more clear about my mistakes.